# In Symfony2 OROCRM datagrid bulk check box update

Tags: symfony-2.8, orocrm

I am not able to use Symfony2 OROCRM data grid view checkbox for multiple update on single click of a button out side the data grid. And can we set popup on selection of data grid rows in Symfony2 OROCRM ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your screen resolution less then 1920x1080?
You can use horizontal scroll, or just hide some columns and pin this grid.

Comment: I tried with only 2 columns. But still its same. Its not the issue of resolution.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and clarify what your issue about?